# Page dimensions when self-publishing an ebook for Kindle with the print replica option?

Tags: kindle, publishing

I want to create a Kindle ebook where I have full control over how every page is displayed. To do that I want to use the Print Replica option of Kindle Create and feed it a PDF that I create via LaTeX.

What are the perfect page settings for the PDF? What height and width come closest to the screen of a standard Kindle? What are good choices for page margins?